# Sharing Image on Twitter via UIActivityController is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

We are developing a feature in our app in which we are trying to tweet an Image. When the app is installed, in the preview of the tweet, the image is not shown. While if the app not installed, it shows the image thumbnail in the preview of the tweet. Also in the installed app case, the tweet doesn’t get posted as well. Posting some screenshots for both scenarios. Wanted to know if the problem described here is related to the issue pointed above and what are the updates on the issue.

Wanted to know if its related to the issue first reported in https://twittercommunity.com/t/bug-in-ios-twitter-app-when-sharing-images-as-nsurl-with-uiactivityviewcontroller/63252/2

Comment: did you added account in your setting >

Comment: Connecting Account in the setting works when we don't install the app. Yes i have connected the twitter account when the app is not installed and it works fine for that case. My question is more about when the app is installed and the user is logged in the app and is trying to post tweet through our ios app using UIActivityController

Comment: i suggest you to use SLComposeViewController for post in social media . because i use this in my project and work fine so

Comment: I got the same problem here, it was working fine until a couple of days, didn't change anything in my app. It's the same release on the App Store and it's always been working fine but now when I tweet, the UIActivityViewController returns `completed` as `true`, but the tweet doesn't appear in my account. I'm logged in the Settings -> Twitter in iOS (10.3.3).

Comment: This is also happening in our app and it seems to be tied to an update of Twitter. One phone with Twitter 7.5 is working, another phone with Twitter 7.7 is not working.

Comment: I almost forgot, both phones are on iOS 10.3.3 and I'm using `SLComposeViewController`.

Comment: 35 minutes ago from twitter staff via twittercommunity.com: "Hi all, thank you for reporting this bug.
The bug fix is in flight for next release for main Twitter app.
Twitter Kit will adopt this change for next release."